# How to connect other mysql in terminal?

Tags: mysql

There are some problems in my mac. One of the Problems is that there are two mysqls in computer. First mysql is executed at localhost and second one is at MAMP. Because of this, when i tryed to connect mysql using php

`<?phpmysqli_connect('localhost','root','$password','dbname') ?>`

, it is connected to MAMP mysql.

And when i tryed to connect mysql using terminal, it is connected to localhost mysql. So i can't do what i want...(When i make some db(named 'dbname') and try to connect at my html, it makes an error
`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (42000/1049): Unknown database 'dbname'`)

What should i do to make it work?..

Comment: kill all the mysql process and start the one you want

Comment: Umm... It didn't work because when i kill localhost mysql process and execute in terminal, it makes an error 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)' means mysql is shutdowned. Same with vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can learn how to connect with mysqli in php here

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

or connect in terminal like this

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql --host=localhost -uroot -proot
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how to thank enough!, And can i ask one more question?